# How to simulate a rich text view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, richtextbox, uitextview, richtext

I want to simulate this kind of rich text view: (From twitter for iPad)[image]
Only the text with the button on the link. ;) How can I place a button on the link? or make the link look as cool as this?

I would like to have this kind of view but I have to be able to select text even id the view is not in editing mode (this is not possible in Twitter app), but when editing it it does not have to be that fancy. A simple UITextView should be enough.

Any ideas how can I achieve this or is there a library out there I can use?

I don't want to use UIWebView since I want to have at least 9 of this views and maybe UIWebView is slow?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

In early versions (iOS2.x) there was a undocumented API in UITextView:

```
[myTextView setContentToHTMLString:@"<body><strong><p>Content In HTML</p></strong><p>Other Paragraph</p></body>"];
```

that still works in iOS4.2! (simulator test). But probably my app will be rejected;(

I also have found this article that support the theory that UITextView still supports HTML but the API is not public:
http://www.lazyrobot.org.uk/2010/06/rich-text-on-iphone.html#comment-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try LRLinkableLabel. 
https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRLinkableLabel
It supports formatting for links, but not richer formats.
Tried it with CoreText yet?

Comment: LRLinkableLabel is probably the fastest way to do it now. I don't think it supports editing mode but I have found a RTF text editor in Omnigroup Frameworks that parses rtf documents very useful. It is like a customized a UITextView that in a future will allow to change font style while editing. (Currently that functionality is disabled) https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor . It's not documented at all and it needs brushhin up but is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with a UIWebView and custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question: [UITextView or UIWebView with normal words looking like links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567953/uitextview-or-uiwebview-with-normal-words-looking-like-links/4568119#4568119)

Here's the answer I provided:

Have you considered the [three20 library](https://github.com/facebook/three20)? In one of its demos, `TTCatalog`, there are samples of displaying exactly what you're looking for. What's great about the project is that you can use HTML to do the styling -- it'll know to convert an anchor, for example, into a clickable button.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Open Source project: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML

This enables you to generate NSAttributedStrings from HTML and the DTAttributedTextCintentView has a delegate method to position a button for the link.